# Field Medic stopped recording crash dumps (reports)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950-xl, feedback, crash

After the Anniversary Update the Field Medic seems to be broken and nobody in Microsoft realized they are not recording the crash dumps of apps and the general stability of the phone.

Previously "I felt good" after having a restart of the phone and look in the "Windows Feedback app" and see a pending report to be send.  And in the Field Medic app it was shown a detail of time of that unexpected restart of the phone in the section of "View Reports" -> uploads.  It was described the title, guid, datetime, and "Uploaded" or something like "Pending to upload".

Since the anniversary update, I don't have a single new report, in Field Medic. The same for the Windows Feedback app, that now it doesn't even have the option of send reports under ... option as before.

Is this still under development yet? Or do they stopped? Or do I have to hard reset the phone...again?

Using Lumia 950 XL, "stable build" 10.0.14393.189. No insiders build.

Comment: Now with version 10.0.14393.321 and after two unexpected restart (crashes) of the phone. Nowhere to be seen the reports.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this still under development yet? Or do they stopped? Or do I have
>   to hard reset the phone...again?

It is perfectly normal. The Feedback Hub automatically uploads reports when you are connected to a WiFi. The option to manually upload feedback data has been removed. That does not prevent Feedback Hub to automatically upload data over WiFi.

---

After the Anniversary update the Feedback Hub now has an option to record the feedback info and attach it to a particular feedback.(See the screenshot below)
[image]

This can be used to manually generate a report, associate it with a specific problem and send it to MS.

---

I ran Field Medic after seeing your question. The report generation is fine. I could see pending uploads,etc...

However in Field Medic there is no option to manually upload reports. This may be removed in favor of Feedback Hub. The report generation using Feedback Hub is more useful to MS. It can be voted upon by others, you can add your reports to others problems.

The field medic is still working. But you cannot upload manually generated reports to MS from Field Medic. Field medic can be used to generate reports on app crashes,etc.. and share it to developer. If you want to share anything to MS Feedback Hub is a better option.

---

> nobody in Microsoft realized they are not recording the crash dumps of
>   apps and the general stability of the phone.

They are recording crash reports and telemetry data. But the process is now fully automated with Feedback Hub.

Comment: I have around 30 reports but since I updated the phone to AU in 23 Aug, there is no single new crash report listed in the application after that date.  And I really really would like that was the case that I had zero crashes or restarts of the phone.  I have one yesterday after I double tap to wake the phone to select a different song in Spotify, and the phone crashed (not just the app).  And what about "Field Medic" nothing...  When I had that before I immediately saw a new report pending to be send on wifi, and after it was sent, I saw it "Uploaded". Not anymore.

Comment: @Allan.C Go to *Settings->Storage->This Device->Temporary files*. See the size of telemetry data. Use your phone for sometime **without connecting to WiFi/any unlimited network**. You should see that the size of telemetry data has been increased. As I said the reports are now collected via Feedback hub and sent. They are cleared after being sent. In Field Medic they are kept. Field medic is no longer used to send data to MS. It is still working and can be used to send reports to other developers. The phone crash reports are no longer sent via Field Medic.

Comment: I think all the time (since the beginning of W10m) Windows Feedback is and was in charge of send reports to MS. But now it is invisible, you cannot see the reports anywhere. Previously you could see the number of pending to send reports in Feedback app, and Field Medic you could see the number and the details of all the crash reports and if it was sent  or not. Now everything is invisible and you have to "trust" everything is working behind the scenes, which is hard to believe because nothing is visible.  That's my whole point.  Crash after crash is "easy" to think something is really broken.

Comment: @Allan.C True. Requests have been made to being back this feature. But sadly no requests has more than 25 votes. Search for *Manually upload feedback* and upvote the ideas in the feedback hub.